# Google places autocomplete search results incomplete

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, google-places-api

Hi we are making an adroid app similar to Uber and use Google places autocomplete api to find source and destination locations on Google Maps. Problem is that our search results are not the same as the search results that i can find directly on Google maps. For instance, If i want to find ITC Haridwar (a factory) then it is easily visible on Google maps but doesn't appear in the search results in my app.

Can anyone suggest me a solution.

Comment: Can you give more details about how you're using the Autocomplete API?  E.g. which method are you calling, and what options you set on the request.  I seem to get the expected result if I try entering "ITC Haridwar" in the live autocomplete demo at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete, so it might be a simple issue in how you're invoking the API.

Comment: Goto google console, make sure you have access to essential APIs. APIs enable on your key will be listed in console.
~ console.developer.google.com

Comment: Please provide the code used to for the Autocomplete. @mayur Rastogi

Comment: @spiv, thanks I was facing some similar issue and your comment along with the link you shared helped me in resolving my issue